# Why do (good) Game-Id questions get so much rep?

Tags: discussion, voting, game-identification

When I say "good" I mean the ones that follow the rules - that provide some example of the game.

I often see these questions pop up, and in just the same way that users pounce on game-id questions that *don't* contain the required information, they similarly promote and praise questions that do.

Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[This question should be migrated to Psychology.SE]*

In all seriousness though, it's probably because Game Identification questions were so polarising in the past; a lot of choice words, arguments, meta-discussions, chat logs, example questions, close/reopen votes and everything else were thrown into the mix, and it took a hell of a lot of people's time, sweat, internet quota, passion and tears to reach the state it's currently in.

Without going into the gory details, it was a complex, large ruling that had large ramifications for how the greater community runs the site to the point that -out of the 5 standardised 'off-topic' close reasons- we have one *purely* dedicated to Game Identification style questions.

So why do we still visit (and vote on) Game-Id questions? **Because we're all (still) heavily invested in the outcome of these discussions.** Both those for and against ITG questions click-through -just to be sure that it conforms to the standards we put in place- and if it does we upvote it whilst we're there.

---

<sub>(Either that or they're just really interesting questions)</sub>

Comment: Also it feels so rare that a user who posts an ITG questions has read the rules surrounding the tag. To the point that when the rules are followed (even if, perhaps, unwittingly), we feel they should be rewarded for following the instructions of the tag.

Comment: @TrentHawkins - Indeed, there's that as well.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but also think it's because we're all a bunch of know-it-alls (we ARE) and we click the question because we expect to be able to answer it easily if there's an artifact from the game there.  If someone else has already answered, it was still worth checking in, and we can leave the upvote on our way out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it has anything to do with how much discussion there was - the majority of our users don't even visit this meta site.

Instead, I think it's because it's rare to see an `identify-this-game` question that meets the requirements, so when we see one we upvote it, sort of like rewarding good behavior.

And sometimes the game looks good, which makes me want to find the game as well.

And then of course, people just love trivia.  On the [Sci-fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) and [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) Stackexchanges, identification questions are allowed without strict rules, but they also get an unusually large number of votes.